# Foreign Key Constraint failed, cascade doesn't delete related object

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, cascade

I have defined `cascade="all, delete-orphan"` and also defined `ondelete="CASCADE"` on the foreign key but still when i delete the customer row which is related to booking I get `"sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey
from database import Base
    
    
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customers"
  
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)
    booking = relationship("Booking", back_populates='customer', cascade="all,delete-orphan")
    
class Booking(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bookings"
 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    cid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("customers.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)
    customer = relationship('Customer', back_populates='booking')
```

```
@app.delete('/customer/{id}')
def destory(id,db:Session = Depends(get_db)):
    customer=db.query(models.Customer).filter(models.Customer.id == id)
    if not customer.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404,
            detail=f'Blog with the id {id} is not available '
        )
    #db.delete(customer.first())
    customer.delete(synchronize_session=False)
    db.commit()
    return 'done'
```

Comment: Did you recreate your database? `CASCADE` is part of the DDL for those tables. If you kept the old database `CASCADE` is not working. I've tested an exact copy of above and it's working fine. Either delete the database file and or use `drop_all` and `create_all`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rfkortekaas , it worked after deleting the database